# How to use custom shaders together with GLKit

Tags: ios5, shader, glkit

I keep reading how wonderfully easy it is to work with GLKit and your own custom shaders. But, so far, I have failed to find any information on how to actually do it. How can I take my own shader and "plug it in" into existing GLKit project?

Comment: From the blog Deli has linked, the solution seems to be as follows:

First, you need the to create 2 files and add them to your project. I call them "fragment.glsl" and "vertex.glsl". Then, at the top of the Controller's .m file, add

#define VERTEX_SHADER @"vertex"
#define FRAGMENT_SHADER @"fragment"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can look at this blog, which uses GLKit to build a basic OpenGL ES 2.0 application. There's also links to other blogs if you're looking to dig more into it:

[GLKit + OpenGL ES 2.0 + iOS5 Programming blog](http://stevezissouprogramming.blogspot.ca/)

The only thing it doesn't cover is GLKBaseEffect, but if you want to build custom shaders like you said, you definitely don't want to use it anyway.

GLKit provides 4 basic things:

1. A math library (Matrices, verctors...)
2. A View/Controller combo made especially for drawing OpenGL content
3. A texture loader class (GLKTextureLoader)
4. GLKBaseEffect, which mimics OpenGL 1.0's fixed pipeline

Comment: *"1. A Matrix, Vector and Quaternion math library which uses NEON so is very high performance.
2. A View/View Controller combo made especially for drawing OpenGL ES content.
3. A texture loader class (GLKTextureLoader).
4. GLKBaseEffect, which mimics OpenGL ES 1.1's fixed pipeline."* This correction is a suggestions from an anonymous user which got rejected. Adding it as a comment here.